# Pandas giving unusual result when using read_csv() with header=None

Tags: python, pandas

When importing the iris data-set for some analysis, when ever i just try to read_csv() with header=None ,all the fields type changes to string , being float initially. But this do-not occur with when header=None is not used.

[image]

Comment: Does it have a header? pandas tries to guess the type and if the headers dont look like numbers, this will happen.

Comment: please don't post screenshots of your code- paste it into your question with [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an expected behaviour. Consider the following demo:

CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Demo:

```
In [179]: pd.read_csv(filename)
Out[179]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
2     7     8     9

In [180]: pd.read_csv(filename).dtypes
Out[180]:
col1    int64
col2    int64
col3    int64
dtype: object
```

if you pass `header=None` - `pd.read_csv()` will treat first row as a data instead of column names (header). Obviously strings like `col1`, `col2` (column names) can't be converted to numeric dtype and thus all columns will have `object` dtype:

```
In [181]: pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
Out[181]:
      0     1     2
0  col1  col2  col3
1     1     2     3
2     4     5     6
3     7     8     9

In [182]: pd.read_csv(filename, header=None).dtypes
Out[182]:
0    object
1    object
2    object
dtype: object
```

using `skiprows=1` you can instruct pandas to ignore (skip) first row:

```
In [183]: pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, skiprows=1)
Out[183]:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [184]: pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, skiprows=1).dtypes
Out[184]:
0    int64
1    int64
2    int64
dtype: object
```

---

PS actually you don't need to ignore column names - most of machine learning algorithms will accept pandas DataFrames (with column names). If you have to pass a Numpy array instead of pandas.DataFrame, then use `df.values`

```
In [185]: df = pd.read_csv(filename)

In [186]: df
Out[186]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
2     7     8     9

In [187]: df.values
Out[187]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int64)

In [188]: type(df.values)
Out[188]: numpy.ndarray
```